# Linear conditional expectations example

Tags: statistics, probability-theory

I am looking for an example of two random variables $X,Y$ such that

(a) $X,Y$ are not independent.

(b) At least one of $X,Y$ is not normal.

(c) $E(X|y)$ (expected value of $X$ given $Y=y$) is linear in $y$, i.e. of the form $a+by$, and $E(Y|x)$ is linear in $x$.

(d) The correlation coefficient $\rho\neq \pm 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general method to get such $X, Y$ is as follows:

Let $Y,Z$ be independent identically distributed random variables. Let $X=Y+Z$. Then as noted above $E(X|y)=y+E(Z)$ is linear in $y$.

And intuitively, $E(Y|x)=E(Z|x)=x/2$. This can be proved rigorously (for continuous case)  as follows:

Suppose the density function for $Y,Z$ is $f(u)$. Then the joint pdf for $X,Y$ is $f(y)f(x-y)$, and the density function for $X$ is the convolution of $f$ with itself. Then
$$ E(Y|x)=\frac{\int y f(y)f(x-y) dy}{\int f(y)f(x-y) dy} .$$ 
This is equal to $x/2$ as shown by Eric Naslund in [this post].

[Proving an integral identity: $\int\nolimits_{-\infty}^\infty x f(x)f(t-x) dx =\frac{t}{2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)f(t-x) dx $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33997/an-integral-identity)

Comment: If $X=2Y+Z$ and $Y,Z$ are independently uniform on $[0,1]$. Then $E(Y|x)=x/4$ for $0<x<1$, $=(2x-1)/4$ for $1<x<2$ and $=(x+1)/4$ for $2<x<3$, showing that it is not linear.

Answer (score 1):

Let $Y$ be any discrete random variable, choose constants $a$ and $b$, and just set $X=aY+b$.  They are not independent, not Gaussian, and the conditional expectations are linear as you wanted.

Comment: You are right. I just added an additional condition.

Answer (score 1):

$Y, Z$ are r.v.'s. Let $X=aY+bZ$. Then the correlation should not be $\pm1$.

Comment: If Y and Z are independent and Y has nonzero density everywhere (so $E[X|Y=y]$ is well-defined), then indeed $E[X|Y=y] = a y + b E[Z]$.  But I don't know about $E[Y | X = x]$.

Comment: @Robert. If $Y,Z$ are independent and both uniform on [0,1] , then  $X=Y+Z$ does give an example where $E(X|y)=\frac{1}{2}+y, E(Y|x)=\frac{1}{2}x$ (if my calculation is correct), $0<y<1, 0<x<2$. However, I still don't know if there is an example where  both $X,Y$ have positive density everywhere.

Comment: If $Y$ has density function $2y,0<y<1$ and $Z$ is uniform
on $[0,1]$, $Y,Z$ independent, $X=Y+Z$. Then according to my calculations
$E(Y|x)=\frac{2}{3}x, 0<x<1$ and $E(Y|x)=\frac{2(x^2-x+1)}{3x}, 1<x<2$.
So $E(Y|x)$ is not linear.

Comment: @TCL You are right. It's more complicated than I thought.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if Y is a binary random variable, then *any* function of Y is linear in Y. For example 
$$
\sin(Y)\;=\;\sin(0)\;+\;(\sin(1)-\sin(0))\cdot Y.
$$
This means that any generic distribution over $\{0,1\}^2$ satisfies your conditions.

By the way, in general, if $E(X|Y)$ is linear in $Y$, then it must be necessarily of the form
$$
E(X|Y)\;=\;E(X)\;+\;\frac{{\rm cov}(X,Y)}{{\rm var}(Y)}(Y-E(Y)).
$$